# Quick Book 2006 with windows 7

Tags: c#-4.0, quickbooks

I am using quickbook 2006 premium edition with windows 7.
Now when i am trying to connect quickbook with c#.net i got the following error on QBSessionManager.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {178AACCA-9DCE-42A0-A193-CF4985B930E5} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

My code is like :

```
public test()
{
InitializeComponent();
sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks 2006 does not run on Windows 7. It's not a supported configuration by Intuit, and from our experiences, doesn't work at all.

Please refer to Intuit's list of supported platforms.
http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/INF12783

Comment: I have several machine. In two of the machine it works perfect. But in other machnine it throws the above error. So is there any configuration required???